# Do counties in Illinois collect individual income tax (IIT)?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, illinois

I did a google search on this issue and I didn't find a firm answer to this question. I did find that in Illinois a county will charge property tax (which varies with county) and there is a flat state level income tax of 4.95%. However, couldn't find anything clearly about the county level IIT for Illinois. Please respond if there is one or not. If there is, then it will be great? If you can, please share a link to IIT rates by county.

Comment: Not a proof of anything, but I lived in Illinois for a while fairly recently and never paid country income taxes

Comment: Same here.  I've lived in Illinois my whole life and I've only ever paid federal and state income tax.  If you buy a house, you will have to pay property tax on that.  That's how a lot of local municipalities get funds for schools, library's, emergency services and such.

Answer (score 3):

A negative is harder to prove than a positive, but [this page](https://www.thebalance.com/cities-that-levy-income-taxes-3193246) suggests that Illinois is not one of the state's that has a county-level income tax.

If you need this information for decision-making purposes, I would recommend contacting the county in question directly.

Comment: [Here](https://taxfoundation.org/local-income-taxes-2019/)'s another source that I've found to be very thorough with tax issues, and they also categorize Illinois as having no local income taxes.

Answer (score 3):

I focused on the state government:[State and Local Taxes Imposed](https://www2.illinois.gov/rev/research/publications/Pages/listofalltaxes.aspx) :

Below are the State and Local Taxes that have fixed rates.

> State Imposed
>
> - Adult Use Cannabis Cultivation Privilege Tax
> - ...
> - Hotel Operator’s Tax
> - Individual Income Tax
> - Liquor Gallonage Tax
> - ...
> - Withholding (Payroll) Tax
>
> Local Imposed
>
> - Illinois Sports Facilities Hotel Tax
> - Metropolitan Pier and Exhibition Authority Tax (Hotel)
> - Municipal Hotel Tax

I also found this:[Income Tax Distributions to Local Governments](https://www2.illinois.gov/rev/localgovernments/Pages/income.aspx)

> What share do local governments receive?
>
> Beginning August 1, 2017, local governments receive 6.06 percent of
> the net collections of all income tax received from individuals,
> trusts, and estates, and 6.85 percent of the net collections of all
> income tax received from corporations.
>
> The amount that each municipality or county receives is based on its
> population in proportion to the total state population.  The
> population figures are determined based on the latest census conducted
> by the United States Census Bureau and certified by the Office of the
> Illinois Secretary of State.

So it appears that local governments get a percent of the state income tax.

Answer (score 2):

Illinois counties collect property tax and sales tax, but not income tax.  (Source: long-time Illinois resident.)

Also see, for example, this proposal to *start* having a Chicago income tax [here](https://ward43.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/City-Income-Tax_vF.pdf), which notes that:

> The   City    does    not impose  an  income  tax on  residents   or  workers in  Chicago.    All residents   of  Illinois,   including   Chicago residents,  are subject to  State   and Federal income  taxes.  The Federal income  tax is  a   progressive income  tax.    The Illinois    income  tax is  a   flat    tax,    with    an  individual  income  tax rate    of  3.75% and   a   corporate   income  tax rate    of  5.25%.  A   portion of  these   State   income  tax revenues    – 8% of individual  income  tax revenue and 9.14% of    corporate   income  tax revenue – flow  into    the Local   Government  Distribution    Fund    (LGDF), from    which   municipalities  are paid    their   share   of  state   income  tax revenue based   on  population.

Comment: Is that quote out of date since the current State Income Tax rate is 4.95%?

Comment: Most likely - I didn’t pay attention to the date. They raised the tax rates a while ago.